# Tool to convert a Python script to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, code-conversion

As my title clearly tells that I need a software or an online tool to convert a given Python code into Matlab code. The resultant Matlab code does not need to be very efficient, I just need a working code. I can try to optimize it on my own.

Note: I know that we can run Python scripts from Matlab, however, in my case, I need Matlab code.

Comment: What libraries does the Python code use? Please list all of the `import` statements, thanks! If your code starts with `import tensorflow` then converting it to Matlab will not be possible, for instance.

Comment: I don't know of any "transpilers" that convert python code by "cut and paste", like the [babeljs online repl](https://babeljs.io/repl) does for converting modern Javascript to old, backwards-compatible Javascript. However, there is a [Cheat Sheet](https://sebastianraschka.com/blog/2014/matrix_cheatsheet_table.html) that compares the syntax of Matlab and Python in a side-by-side view, using lots and lots of one-line code-examples. Hope this helps. By the way, do you know *any* language that can be automatically transpiled to Matlab/Octave?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Currently, I do not import any libraries. They are very basic, simple small scripts.

Comment: @knb Thanks for the link, that cheat sheet might be very helpful. Unfortunately, I do not know such transpilers, I am a newbie about Matlab.